# Ansible if nested value doesn't exist in nested array

Tags: ansible-facts

I'd like to make my Ansible EIP creation idempotent. In order to do that I only want the task to run when Tag "Name" value "tag_1" doesn't exist.
However I'm not sure how I could add this as a 'when' at the end of a task.

```
    "eip_facts.addresses": [
    {
        "allocation_id": "eipalloc-blablah1", 
        "domain": "vpc", 
        "public_ip": "11.11.11.11", 
        "tags": {
            "Name": "tag_1", 
        }
    }, 
    {
        "allocation_id": "eipalloc-blablah2", 
        "domain": "vpc", 
        "public_ip": "22.22.22.22", 
        "tags": {
            "Name": "tag_2", 
        }
    }, 
    {
        "allocation_id": "eipalloc-blablah3", 
        "domain": "vpc", 
        "public_ip": "33.33.33.33", 
        "tags": {
            "Name": "tag_3", 
        }
    }
]
```

(Tags are added later) I'm looking for something like:

```
- name: create elastic ip 
  ec2_eip:
    region: eu-west-1
    in_vpc: yes
  when: eip_facts.addresses[].tags.Name = "tag_1" is not defined
```

What is the correct method of achieving this? Bear in mind the value can not exist in that parameter in the entire array, not just a single iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a semi-decent solution

```
- name: Get list of EIP Name Tags
  set_fact:
    eip_facts_Name_tag: "{{ eip_facts.addresses | map(attribute='tags.Name') | list }}"
```

Which extracts the Name tag and puts them into an array

```
ok: [localhost] => {
"msg": [
    "tag_1", 
    "tag_2", 
    "tag_3"
  ]
}
```

and then...

```
- debug: 
    msg: "Hello"
  when: '"tag_1" in "{{ eip_facts_Name_tag }}"'
```

This will work, beware though, this doesn't do an exact string search. So if you did a search for just 'tag' that'd count as a hit too.